# Stopping this SUID program reading any other files

Tags: c, linux, debian

This program has a vulnerability that allows users to read any of the user's files through hard links. How do I stop this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  printf("              UID             GID \n"
        "Real   %d  Real        %d \n"
        "Effective %d  Effective %d \n",
        getuid (),      getgid (),
        geteuid(),      getegid());
        
        
  FILE *fp = fopen("File1", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char c;
  while ((c=getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any advice would be brilliant!

Comment: LOL, most brilliant advice: delete the program. I think you should create a user that has the limited rights you want, and then SUID the program for that user, instead of your user account, or whoever owns the program. But I am not a *nix guy.  Perhaps this really isn't an SO kind of problem. The code obviously works, so maybe you should try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for this sort of thing?

Comment: Use the absolute pathname to the file, instead of accessing the file in the directory of the person running the program.